# What factors are best for image resizing?

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics, image-resizing

Let's say I have an image that is 3000 px wide. I know (at least I think I do) that if I downsize it to be 1500 px wide (that is, 50%), the result will be better than if I resize it to be 1499 or 1501 px wide.

I suppose that will be so regardless of the algorithm used. But I have no solid proof, and the reason I'd like to have proof is that it could help me decide less obvious cases.

For instance, reducing it to 1000 px (one third) will also presumably work ok. But what about 3/4? Is it better than 1/2? It certainly can hold more detail, but will part of it not become irretrievably fuzzy? Is there a metric for the 'incurred fuzziness' which can be offset against the actual resolution?

For instance, I suppose such a metric would clearly show 3000 -> 1501 to be worse than 3000 -> 1500, more than is gained by 1501 > 1500.

Intuitively, 1/n resizes where n is a factor of the original size would yield the best results, followed by n/m where the numbers were the lowest possible. Where the original size (both X and Y) were not a multiple of the denominator, the results are expected to be poorer, tho I have no proof of that.

These issues must have been studied by someone. People have devised all sorts of complex algorithms, they must take this somehow in consideration. But I don't even know here to ask these questions. I ask them here because I've seen related ones with good answers. Thanks for your attention and please excuse the contrived presentation.

Comment: [Image scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) is a big topic, and your question is probably too broad to be addressed here. The general answer to your question is, "it depends." It depends on what algorithm is used to do the sampling. *In general*, the only thing you can say is that the more you shrink the image, the more information you lose. With modern scaling algorithms, it's highly unlikely that shrinking from 3000 to 1500 will look better than shrinking to 1600. Or even 1550.

Comment: More to the point, your intuition seems based on the idea that scaling is done by removing every `nth` pixel, so that scaling 3000 to 1500 would simply remove every other pixel. That's not how most scaling algorithms work. Instead, they work by examining areas of the image, and picking representative colors. That sampling and selection process can be quite complex.

Comment: @JimMischel, your second comment is more or less to the point. No, I'm not assuming pixels will be removed, rather that the representative blocks would work better it they were integer factors of the original. But I see from the two answers I got that none of the best algorithms work in such a simple way as to be much influenced by this. I was thinking mostly of 'pixel resize', where each pixel would be built from an n*n block of the original, and would still like to have an answer for that.

Comment: What you call "pixel resize" is what I called "pixel averaging" in my answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom indeed it seems so. Do you know of a discussion of the issue? Of course the results will be uneven across different images, but has anyone studied how to quantify it generally?

Answer (score 4):

The algorithm is key. Here's a list of common ones, from lowest quality to highest. As you get higher in quality, the exact ratio of input size to output size makes less of a difference. By the end of the list you shouldn't be able to tell the difference between resizing to 1499 or 1500.

1. Nearest Neighbor, i.e. keeping some pixels and dropping others.
2. Bilinear interpolation. This takes the 2x2 area of pixels around the point where your ideal sample would be, and calculates a new value based on how close its position is to each of the 4 pixels. It doesn't work well if you're reducing below 2:1 because it starts to resemble nearest neighbor.
3. Bicubic interpolation. Similar to Bilinear but using a 3x3 area with a more complex formula to get sharper results. Again not good below 2:1.
4. Pixel averaging. If this isn't done with an integer multiple of input to output you'll be averaging different amounts each time and the results will be uneven.
5. Lanczos filtering. This takes a number of pixels from the input and runs them through a modified version of Sinc that attempts to retain as much of the detail as possible while keeping the calculations tractable. The size and speed of the filter varies with the resizing ratio. It's slow, but not as slow as Sinc.
6. Sinc filtering. This is theoretically perfect, but it requires processing a large chunk of input for every pixel output so it's very slow. You may also notice the difference between theory and practice when you see ringing artifacts in the output.

Comment: Your answer is more to the point, and the discussion of algorithms is welcome. It still doesn't answer my question, but it shows why it may be moot.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question:

1. Most important factor is choosing a good re-sizing algorithm. For example, bi-cubic interpolation will not work well if you re-size by factor > 2 and do not apply smoothing. Unfortunately there is no best algorithm. If you are using photoshop or other advanced resizing tool you may chose the algorithm. In 'Picasa' you cannot choose. Each algorithm has its downsides. Some are better for natural images, other for computer graphic generated image
2. Less important factor is round division. The larger the output image size the better results you will get but the file will take more megabytes. Re-scaling from 3000 pix to 1600 will give you visually better results than re-scaling to 1500.
3. Another factor - amount of rescales. Resizing an image from 3000 to 2000 and than to 1500 will produce slightly worse result than direct resize from 3000 to 1500. Each time you resize the image, some information is lost
4. Friendly advice: keep the size of your image (both height and width) divisible by 4. For example 1501 is a bad size, 1500 or 1504 is better. The reason is that some hardware deal faster with images with size divisible by 4. Though quality will not improve, your browsing experience will be better.
5. If you display your image on a computer screen, try to match its size to the size of your screen. Otherwise the display process will make another resampling and you will not be able to observe the true beauty of your image.
6. If you intend to print your image, better have a high resolution. You will need at least 300 dpi. So if you want to print it on 10 inch paper, leave it at least 3000 pixels.
7. The last one is obvious, but I will mention it: try to keep the original aspect ratio when you resize the image. Otherwise it will become distorted. So if you downscale it from 3000 width to 1499, then you will not be able to choose an integer for image height to keep the original aspect ratio.
8. JPEG compression will harm you image much more than the difference in visual quality between 1500 pix image and 1499. Keep that in mind. Even with slight compression you will not be able to see the difference in quality

As a summary - stop worrying about image exact size. Choose a modern resampling algorithm (if you can), roughly estimate the size as a trade-of between size on disk, image quality and printing paper size (if relevant).
Keep the original aspect ratio and remember that JPEG compression will harm your image much more than the difference in visual quality of different resampling algorithms or slight variation in image size.

Comment: I think your answer is valuable because all of your points are good and bear repeating, but my question is a mathematical, not a perceptual one.